# Integração LaTex e Python ou R

Tags: python, r, latex

Olá, tenho um projeto que envolve automatização de relatórios. Atualmente todos os relatórios são feitos por meio de word e os gráficos no excel, agora estou tentando implententar uma aplicação que gera os gráficos automáticamente na `linguagem R` e queria que esses gráficos fossem formatados em um bonito banner no `LaTex` (sempre ouvi falar bem desse compliador de textos).

Nessa aplicação estou usando: `R` logicamente para os gráficos, `python` para manipulação de dados e integração com bancos `mysql`.

Os gráficos são feitos no `R`, mas dá para fazer no `python` também, pois uso a biblioteca `ggplot2`, que é aceito em ambos.

E nisso queria integrar tudo isso no final no `LaTex` gerando o arquivo.

Neste caso eu gostaria de direções, orientações e dicas se possível.

Comment: Essa pergunta esté bem tendenciosa a ser fechada, pois quase tudo depende de opiniões. Dando a minha: Crie os graficos e salve em EPS: Latex gosta de EPS.

Comment: Eu acho que dá pra fazer o que você quer com jupyter, rmarkdown, sweave ou org-mode do emacs. Provavelmente outros que eu não conheço. Dá uma pesquisada melhor, veja qual deles é melhor para o seu caso e refaça a pergunta de modo mais específico. Do jeito que está, ficou muito aberta.

Comment: @MarcosBanik, sou bastante leigo em latex, resolvi me aventurar nele ontem e quebrei muita a cabeça, precisava mais de uma orientação mesmo e acho que a pergunta fez o seu papel. Vou estudar mais centrado agora com as orientações fornecidas aqui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neste caso, a melhor solução é utilizar o `rmarkdown`. Para ter uma ideia de como ele funciona, abra o RStudio e vá no menu `File > New File > R Markdown...`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Escolha as opções Document e PDF (note que o LaTeX precisa estar instalado para funcionar):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isto vai te gerar um arquivo .Rmd. O arquivo padrão tem o conteúdo abaixo:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Marcus Nunes"
date: "3/12/2018"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Se tu estiver usando Windows, é só usar o atalho Ctrl+Shift+K para compilar o documento.

Se não for possível utilizar o RStudio, tem outras maneiras de compilar o relatório, mas elas são mais complicadas do que simplesmente rodar Ctrl+Shift+K. Eu escrevi há alguns anos uns scripts no bash pra fazer isto, mas migrei pro RStudio pela facilidade que o programa me gera.

Tem diversas referências sobre R Markdown na internet. [Este é um bom curso sobre o assunto](https://github.com/mnunes/Curso-RMarkdown) (disclaimer: eu escrevi ele).

Comment: muito obrigado novamente, vou seguir o seu curso que parece ser bem intuitivo.

Comment: Modéstia à parte, as pessoas que fizeram gostaram bastante (ou ao menos me disseram isso).

Answer (score 5):

Primeiramente, não sou familiar com a linguagem Python, então vou focar na linguagem R.
Para a manipulação de dados com o R e sql, você pode dá uma olhada no pacote `RSQLite` que é particularmente bem feito.

Considerando que você faz a manipulação de dados e gráficos no `R` e o relatório via `LaTeX`, aqui vão algumas opções para realizar as análises, gráficos e relatório de forma automática e reproduzível:

**1. R et LaTeX integrados por um `makefile`**

`make` é uma forma de automatizar processos que você iria fazer à mão no seu sistema. No seu exemplo, você iria codar um script makefile para, em primeiro, rodar o escript R/python para fazer as análises, em seguida rodar o script R para criar os gráficos e salvar numa pasta e então rodar o escript LaTeX para criar o relatório utilizando os outputs dos scripts anteriores.

Positivo: flexibilidade completa para cada etapa realizada e boa organização de cada script do projeto.

Negativo: makefile é um pouco difícil de criar e é nativo para os sistemas linux e iOS. Não sei como funciona no Windows.

**2. R et LaTeX integrados por [`Sweave`](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552056-Using-Sweave-and-knitr)**

`Sweave` é uma extensão `.Rnw` do `knitr` que permite incorporar código R nos documentos LaTeX para gerar um arquivo PDF. Em resumo, você escreve o relatório em laTex e para cada análise/gráfico, você incorpora o código R.

Positivo: flexível e fácil de usar se você conhece LaTeX

Negativo: tenho a impressão que há poucos utilizadores comparado com `Rmarkdown`, o que torna um pouco mais difícil de resolver problemas online.

**3. R et LaTeX integrados por [`Rmarkdown`](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com)**

`Rmarkdown` é um pacote do R que permite incorporar código R nos documentos markdown. Tem praticamente a mesma abordagem que `Sweave`, só que mais flexível pois permite exportar para diversas extensões (pdf, html, word...).

Positivo: Mais amigável e simples para aprender se você não conhece LaTeX. Além da sintaxe mais limpa.

Negativo: A formatação do relatório não é tão flexível como LaTeX. Mas o interessante é que você pode incorporar os estilos LaTeX ou html no documento.

Em conclusão, pessoalmente acredito que `Rmarkdown` será a maneira mais fácil e rápida para realizar teus objetivos.

Comment: agradeço a resposta. Juntando sua resposta com a do Marcus, `Rmarkdown` me pareceu melhor opção por agora, mas fiquei bem interessado no `Sweave`. Eu quis botar o `LaTex`no meio disso tudo para também usa-lo no futuro, na elaboração do meu TCC , tentando unir o útil ao agradável.

Comment: Eu comecei neste mundo de geração de relatórios e apresentações de slides automatizados utilizando Sweave. Ele tem seu mérito e eu ainda uso muito, pois tenho toneladas de legacy code que escrevi pra ele. Mas Sweave é um produto de outra época, mais bruta. É bem menos intuitivo do que o `rmarkdown`. Se eu fosse indicar algo para um iniciante, que parece ser o teu caso, eu não pensaria duas vezes antes de recomendar o `rmarkdown`.

Comment: Concordo com o Marcus. Além do mais, você pode aproveitar toda a flexibilidade de formatação do LaTeX inserindo um `style` LaTeX no documento `Rmarkdown`.